# Problem about a sequence of independent random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$, show that for any bounded random variable $Y$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Bbb{E}(X_nY)=0$.

I don't  know how to use the independent condition. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: independent r.v. have covariance zero, hence the expected value of their product ist the product of their expected values.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thank you, sir. But I still don't see how to solve the problem using your hint, could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with $L^{2}$ space and expansions w.r.t. orthonormal sets then this result is immediate. The given sequence is orthonormal in $L^{2}$ so $EX_nY \to 0$ for every $Y \in L^{2}$, in particular for bounded $Y$. In fact much more is true: $\sum_n (EX_nY)^{2} \leq EY^{2} <\infty$.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Nicely observed! +1